# How to improve my c++ code's runtime efficency

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm doing a leetcode problem [986. Interval List Intersections](https://leetcode.com/problems/interval-list-intersections/), I don't know why my O(m+n) solution, even the official solution only beats 5% submissions on runtime. How other people make it runs faster? Is there any ways or suggestions to improve my code? Thanks a lot.

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> intervalIntersection(vector<vector<int>>& A, vector<vector<int>>& B) {
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        while(i < A.size() && j < B.size()) {
            int lo = max(A[i][0], B[j][0]);
            int hi = min(A[i][1], B[j][1]);
            if(lo <= hi) {
                vector<int> temp{lo, hi};
                res.push_back(temp);
            }
            if(A[i][1] <= B[j][1]) 
                ++i;
            else
                ++j;
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As a quick thought: memory allocation is quite expensive, try to [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) some memory on `res` before pushing elements to it. Also (even if it's required by the task) it's a waste to use a `vector` that will only ever contain two elements for the same reason. `std::pair<int, int>` or `std::array<int, 2>` would be better suited here.

Comment: Since parameters are passed by (non-const) reference, you can avoid any memory allocation, just edit in-place one of the two vectors and return that.

Comment: `res.emplace_back(std::move(temp));` might be marginally faster

Comment: It's somewhat arbitrary. When I run your code multiple times, the runtime measured by Leet code can vary between 64-140ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've done it for you. See my comments in the code.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> intervalIntersection(vector<vector<int>>& A, vector<vector<int>>& B) {
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        // Avoid reallocations, reserve enough memory.
        res.reserve(A.size() + B.size());
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        // Hint to the compiler: A.size() and B.size() are immutable.
        const int ii = A.size(), jj = B.size();
        while(i < ii && j < jj) {
            const int lo = max(A[i][0], B[j][0]);
            const int hi = min(A[i][1], B[j][1]);
            if(lo <= hi) {
                // Construct inner vector in-place.
                res.push_back(std::vector<int>({lo, hi}));
            }
            if(A[i][1] <= B[j][1]) 
                ++i;
            else
                ++j;
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

The result:

Runtime: 56 ms, faster than 46.23% of C++ online submissions for Interval List Intersections.

Memory Usage: 13 MB, less than 100.00% of C++ online submissions for Interval List Intersections.

Accepted    56 ms   13 MB   cpp